# Kotlin: fix Overload Resolution Ambiguity with buildString

Tags: kotlin

I recently was on a meetup where I got to see some things build with Kotlin and wanted to try it out myself. But I am having a hard time even to run the code... I am always getting this error:
[image]
Since I am new I have no idea how to approach this problem. I found some similar issues, but they were solved by casting the variables, but the functions look nearly identical, except the comment there.
You can find the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jonnyzzz/kotlin-fractals/blob/master/js/src/main/kotlin/main.kt#L93).
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Code snippet:

```
document.getElementById("jvmLink").unsafeCast<HTMLDivElement>().innerHTML = buildString {
    appendHTML().a(href = "$url&jvm=false", target = "_blank") {
        +"Open JVM image in new window"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use a fully qualified name of the function? You can also `import ... as ...` to make names separate for objects that have identical names in different packages.

Comment: I have tried it, but my attempts were not successful. I am also not sure if I did it right. I am also having a problem with the appendHTML, which is being treated as unresolved reference, but the library import kotlinx.html.stream.appendHTML is being imported.

Comment: I suspect something's hosed with your installation. It seems to have two different versions of `buildString()`, both coming from `kotlin.text` (one reason you can't resolve it by qualified names!). The first version seems to have come from translating java (which I would expect) and the second version is a bit of a mystery. If I have time I'll try to look at one of my installations. Are you using IntelliJ or Android Studio?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20406

Comment: Plz try compile your code (instead of just look at the error msg), it may compile (since it's probably an IDE bug, not a compiler bug).